# How to change the wavelength of LEDs in Proteus?

Tags: led, simulation, light, proteus, wavelength

I have a problem in designing a circuit for my project.

Can anyone explain how to simulate an LED with 940, 1550, and 1650 nm in Proteus software?

Dors the emission coefficient of LEDs in Proteus help to change or control the eavelength of light produced in the simulation model?

[image]

Comment: I have never used Proteus but usually circuit simulators cannot simulate optical effects like wavelength.

Comment: That has no effect. The wavelength is due to material bandgap energy. do you have a part number? Those variables only simulate the Part you want to model including thermal resistance and temp rise